# Smoke.js in php

Tags: php, javascript

I have a php function that validates HTML form fields.
When an error occurs the following
code will generate an error message using java script "alert":

```
 echo '<script type= "text/javascript">alert("account not found in database")</script>';
```

I would like to use "smoke.js".
I have downloaded the code for smoke.js, smoke.min.js into the js directory/folder and smoke.css into the css directory/folder.
I have tried the following"

```
 echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="smoke.js"</script>';
 echo '<script type="text/javascript">smoke.alert("account not found in database")</script>';
```

nothing happens.
I have searched for similar usage but found nothing.

Comment: Can you please provide us some code? Thanks.

Comment: Open your browser's developer tools/error console (`F12` in most browsers). It will show you what the problem is. If it's not entirely clear to you, post that error so we can see it.

Comment: You said you put in in the js directory, so you probably should set the `src` to `/js/smoke.js` or something. Also if there seems to be something wrong, always take a look at the browsers console to locate the error.

Comment: If you put your trial on some webhosting space we can see easier what you did wrong.

Comment: It looks like you are missing a `>`. First line should be `echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="smoke.js"></script>';`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="smoke.js"></script>';
```

http://smoke-js.com/docs/

Answer (score 0):

try to put it in divs

```
echo'<script type="text/javascript" src="smoke.js"></script>';
   echo'<div>';
 echo '<script type="text/javascript">smoke.alert("account not found in database")</script>';
   echo'</div>';
```

works!